# Parse and print Excel cell data based on count using python

Tags: python, excel, csv

I have to parse an excelsheet based on column data. for example I have 4 comma separated values in 'column 2', I want to print 4 lines, each line containing 1 value from column 2.

[image]

I am getting output like this.

```
1,2,abc,def,ghi,jkl,11,10,10
3,4,abc,def,ghi,jkl,12,12,11
```

expected output would be like this.

```
1,2,abc,11,10,10
1,2,def,11,10,10
1,2,ghi,11,10,10
1,2,jkl,11,10,10
3,4,abc,12,12,11
3,4,def,12,12,11
3,4,ghi,12,12,11
3,4,jkl,12,12,11
```

I can read whole data but not getting output like this. Please guide me how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have this kind of list after reading the excel file:

```
file_content = [
      ['1,2', 'abc,def,ghi,jkl', 11, 10, 10], 
      ['3,4', 'abc,def,ghi,jkl', 12, 12, 11]
]
```

One way to achieve your goal, is to iterate over each value of the column 2 splitted by coma and 'rebuilt' a entire row. With something like:

```
output = list()

for row in file_content:
    for elt in row[1].split(','):
        # handle values of column 1 which are also coma separated
        tmp = [int(x) for x in row[0].split(',')
        # append one value of column 2
        tmp.append(elt)
        # merge with the end of the row
        tmp += row[2:]

        output.append(tmp)
```

**EDIT:**

To read your excel file you should use the [pandas library](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/) and adapt the code above as follow:

```
import pandas

df = pandas.read_excel('yourfile.xlsx', header=None)
output = list()

for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    for elt in row[1].split(','):
        tmp = [int(x) for x in row[0].split(',')]
        tmp.append('elt')
        tmp += list(row[2:])
        output.append(tmp)
```

Comment: and how can we get file_content data? As I stated in my question I am getting full row1 from excel. Not getting data as you showed in your example.

Comment: Okidoki I have not understand your post this way. To read and parse your excel file you should take a look at the pandas library. I edited my answer in consequence.